# Cordova build fail for iOS 11 with XCode 9.0.1 Remote debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, cordova-plugins, ios11, visual-studio-cordova

With my cordova app with taco in VS, when I try to remote build(VS in windows to Mac) it gives this part of error lines.

```
ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["Device313876570","Device","getDeviceInfo",[]]
ERROR: Plugin 'File' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["File313876571","File","requestAllPaths",[]]
[MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

for me it seems like problems with the 2 plugins,

- **cordova-plugin-device** (v1.1.7) and
- **cordova-plugin-file** (v4.3.3)

VS Cordova tool-set version **6.3.1**

does anybody encounter this kind of situation and any suggestions?

Comment: This is a plugin specific issue will solved by removing and adding again.